# java android create event

Tags: java, android, events, event-handling

I wish to create event which will react on change of int/ eventually Integer variable. 
When the variable reaches some special value I wish to run some method (e.g. stopservice method). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). This can be adapted and used for your situation.

There are great resources for this already available on the internet.